Federated Query between two RDFlib graphs
I have two local knowledge graphs in the form of turtle files.
Let's say they look something like:
File1 - people.ttl
Bob a person ;
    feeds cat-1 ;
    trains dog-1 ;
    owns house-1 .

File 2 - houses.ttl
house-1 a house ;
    worth "$500k" ;
    has_address "123 Road Dr." .

if I load these into rdflib as pplGraph and hsGraph:
from rdflib import Graph

pplGraph = Graph().parse('people.ttl')
hsGraph = Graph().parse('houses.ttl')

is there a way to do a federated query between them? Say I want to know the cost of every person's house, how would I write that query?
I know I could do something like:
for s,p,o in hsGraph.triples((None, None, None)):
    pplGraph.add((s,p,o))

and then do a non-federated query, but is it possible to keep the two separate and just use the query method?

Hi, querying multiple graphs locally I'd more consider as querying a dataset and no  federated querying is needed here - a dataset in RDF comprises multiple RDF graphs. Support for datasets does exist in rdflib, check https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/apidocs/rdflib.html#rdflib.Dataset - let us know if you need more guidance

Thank you for that info!  In terms of SPARQL queries from the dataset, what needs to change? Can I just use ds.query() instead of g.query()? I'm still quite new to SPARQL, so it's not clear to me how I would restrict query returns to one graph or another.

Okay, I think I figured it out. FROM clauses! https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#rdfDataset

Either FROM which makes up the graph or even a union of multiple graphs being queried. Or you can just use the GRAPH keyword inside the query pattern, e.g. SELECT * WHERE {GRAPH :g1 {?s ?p ?o .} }
